# nothing is shown in "Workspace" area

Tags: cloud9-ide

I installed Cloud9 in my local Ubuntu server as follows.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/c9/core.git cloud9
$ cd cloud9
$ ./scripts/install-sdk.sh
```

Launching cloud9 server with pm2.

```
$ pm2 start cloud9.json
```

cloud9.json

```
{
"name" : "cloud9",
"script" : "server.js",
"cwd" : "/home/user/cloud9",
"args" : ["-a", ":", "-w", "/home/user/workspace", "-p", "8181", "-l", "0.0.0.0"]
}
```

Then I tried to connect to it from other windows PC with Chrome browser.
Connection was successful and Welcome screen appeared.

But no files appeared in "Workspace" area and a circle icon kept on spinning.
It seems loading file is not finished.

In addition, I found a "terminal" function also does not work.
When I selected "Open a Terminal", a new tab "Terminal" opened but no prompt appeared there.
Then I input some key in terminal window, "Terminal was disconnected. Trying to reconnect" is shown.

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Did there any errors when installing the sdk, or browser console, or the console where you run server.js? Also try running it without pm2

Comment: I tried to run cloud9 without pm2 like "node server.js -p 8181 -l 0.0.0.0 -a :", but I got the same result. After that I ran install-sdk.sh again. (some packages seem updated). Then I got another problem.
Process dead several seconds after launching with following error.
<pre>
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
</pre>